# Snapshot of table row instance with time intervals

Tags: sql, analytics, teradata, data-warehouse, window-functions

I am not sure what to call this phenomenon. I have just titles it with "Snapshot of table row instance with time intervals". We have a situation where we need to create a new entity which is kind of JOIN of two tables but these two tables have history and that history we need to merge into this entity. Please have a look at example below:

[image: Problem Scenario]

In the image you can see we have two tables ABC and PQR with ID as key column. We need to create one table ABCPQR which will be join of this both table and they history of this table will contains merged history of both attribute from their respective tables.

How to implement this in database? I am using Teradata as database, Is there any algorithm available to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make quick work of this with Teradata's PERIOD data type. A period is a range of dates or timestamps. It takes two dates or timestamps as arguments the first for the start date and the second for the end date (up to but not including).

In your case we'll convert your `Start_Date` and `End_Date` to Periods to perform the join. We will use the Period specific function `P_INTERSECT` to find overlapping periods on which we will join.

```
SELECT
    attr1,
    attr2,
    /*pull the BEGIN of the intersected period*/
    BEGIN(t1.validperiod P_INTERSECT t2.validperiod) as startdate,
    /*pull the END of the intersected period (subtracting a day since period end
      dates are "up to but not including")*/
     PRIOR(END(t1.validperiod P_INTERSECT t2.validperiod)) as enddate   
FROM
    (SELECT abc.*, PERIOD(start_date, NEXT(end_date)) as validperiod FROM abc) t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT pqr.*, PERIOD(start_Date, NEXT(end_date)) as validperiod FROM pqr) t2 ON
        t1.id = t2.id 
        /*
        * Now P_INTERSECT our two periods and look for Non-Null intersections
        * The intersection is the date range where the two periods overlap
        */
        AND t1.validperiod P_INTERSECT t2.validperiod IS NOT NULL;
```

There's a few bonuses that we pick up here:

1. The logic is clean and simple. No testing for max(start_date) and min(end_date) with nested CASE statements and all that horribleness
2. If you have to join in a third table, just convert it's start and end date to validperiod and join with `t1.validperiod P_INTERSECT t2.validperiod P_INTERSECT t3.validperiod IS NOT NULL` Simple simple.
3. There are a handful of other really useful functions that are period based that will make work like this a snap. NORMALIZE will merge multiple records together based on a composite key and overlapping and meeting periods, for instance.

Lastly, as a rule, when I'm creating tables and that table has start date and end date I ALWAYS create a new field called validperiod and load it like we do in those subqueries. Then you don't have to convert to period for your joins to be friendly. Just grab your already stored validperiod column and start P_INTERSECTing. It takes all the work out of otherwise ugly joins and selects.

Comment: Hi JNevill. Thanks for your answer but wanted to ask quick question. Do you have idea how does P_INTERSECT performs when we join multiple tables.

Comment: Its pretty fast. I have one that p_intersects 6 or 7 tables each with tens of thousands of records and it returns in a minute or so. That one is also all left joins so I coalesce each possible intersection.

Comment: I realized I stated in the comments that I was taking the end(period) - 1 but forgot to implement that in the SQL. I've updated the answer for the field to: `Prior(End(t1.validperiod P_INTERSECT t2.validperiod))`. Also, you may find it worthwhile to check out this older blog post about Teradata's Period functionality: http://downloads.teradata.com/partners/oracle/articles/exploring-teradata-13s-period-functions  It's a great resource with examples and explanations.

Comment: Also, I just ran the big P_INTERSECT sql I mentioned in that 2nd comment here. It takes 6 tables, each table has between 200k and 600k records and it outputs 663746 records to a new table in 2-3 seconds on our single node box.

Answer (score 0):

No complex algorithm. Simple sql with cross-join , between and greatest/least function will do.

```
create table abc 
( id integer,
attr1 varchar(3),
start_date date,
end_date date)
PRIMARY INDEX(ID);


create table PQR 
( id integer,
attr2 varchar(3),
start_date date,
end_date date)
PRIMARY INDEX(ID);

INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1,'LMN','2017-01-01','2017-02-28');
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1,'HGI','2017-02-28','2017-03-15');
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1,'STI','2017-03-15','2099-12-31');


INSERT INTO PQR VALUES(1,'KLM','2017-01-01','2017-01-20');
INSERT INTO PQR VALUES(1,'TLF','2017-01-20','2017-04-04');
INSERT INTO PQR VALUES(1,'SNQ','2017-04-04','2099-12-31');


select a.id,a.attr1,p.attr2,
        cast(greatest(cast(a.start_date as int),cast(p.start_date as int)) as date)start_date,
        cast(least(cast(a.end_date as int),cast(p.end_date as int)) as date)end_date
from abc a
inner join pqr p
on a.id=p.id
where a.start_date between p.start_date and p.end_date
or a.end_date between p.start_date and p.end_date
order by 4;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    id  attr1   attr2   start_date  end_date
1   1   LMN KLM 1/1/2017    1/20/2017
2   1   LMN TLF 1/20/2017   2/28/2017
3   1   HGI TLF 2/28/2017   3/15/2017
4   1   STI TLF 3/15/2017   4/4/2017
5   1   STI SNQ 4/4/2017    12/31/2099
```

Only difference is I took 2099 instead of 1999 to make thing easy. you can use 1999 as well and customize this query(not preferred though).

Comment: Thanks for Answer Bhavesh.